# convert_dtypes over dataframe from json not identifying types

Tags: python, json, pandas, dtype

I have a json document and I want to identify the data types for as many keys as possible.

The JSON file is:

```
{
  "id":"420",
  "name":"Myplace",
  "modified":"2022-03-02T18:30:09.01+01:00",
  "status":"0",
  "coordinates":"[[7275.091,3728.153],[72807.585,372757.906]]"
}
```

and the code I run is:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('file.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(dfn.dtypes)
dfn = df.convert_dtypes()

print(dfn.dtypes)
```

And the output:

```
id              object
name            object
modified        object
status          object
coordinates     object
dtype: object

id              string
name            string
modified        string
status          string
coordinates     string
dtype: object
```

As you can see initially everything is considered as `object`. And afterwards all of them are strings. However `id` and `status` can be converted to numbers (i.e. `integer`).

How can I make it to have integer/float strings and datetime strings recognized as integer/float and Date?

Any help is more than welcome.

***Edit: Potential solution***

I have continued working on it, and using other functions I have managed to achieve something. But I will be nice to do it in just one step.

```
result = pd.json_normalize(data)

dfs = pd.to_datetime(result.squeeze(), errors='coerce')
non_nan = pd.isna(dfs) == False
result.loc[0][non_nan] = dfs[non_nan]

dfs = pd.to_numeric(result.squeeze(), errors='coerce')
non_nan = pd.isna(dfs) == False
result.loc[0][non_nan] = dfs[non_nan]

dfn = result.convert_dtypes(infer_objects=True, \
                            convert_string=True, \
                            convert_integer=True, \
                            convert_boolean=True, \
                            convert_floating=True)

print(dfn.dtypes)
```

And now the output is:

```
id                                             Int64
name                                          string
modified        datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]
status                                         Int64
coordinates                                   string
```

Then I still have to find out if I can find out if the string is an array or just an string. This would be great ;)